# How to add sharepoint navigation child menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, quick-launch

JavaScript it is possible to add navigation nodes in a SharePoint site.
 In the following example we define the new nodes in an array at the beginning. The code block takes this array and sets the navigation

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var navArray = [
{ title:"Home", url:"/sites/gms-portal", isExternal:false },
{ title:"Microsoft", url:"http://www.microsoft.com", isExternal:true },
{ title:"Google", url:"http://www.google.com", isExternal:true },
{ title:"Bing", url:"http://www.bing.com", isExternal:true }
];

function checkArray() {
    for (var i = 0; i < navArray.length; i++) {
        var navObject = navArray[i];

        alert(navObject.title);
    }
}

var navigationNodeCollection = null;
var nnci = null;

function addNavigationNodes() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        // Get the Quick Launch navigation node collection.
        // this.quickLaunchNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_quickLaunch();

        // Get the Top Navigation navigation node collection.
        this.navigationNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_topNavigationBar();

        for (var i = 0; i < navArray.length; i++) {
            var navObject = navArray[i];
            var navTitle = navObject.title;
            var navUrl = navObject.url;
            var navIsExternal = navObject.isExternal;

            // Set properties for a new navigation node.
            this.nnci = new SP.NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
            nnci.set_title(navTitle);
            nnci.set_url(navUrl);
            nnci.set_isExternal(navIsExternal);

            // Create node as the last node in the collection.
            nnci.set_asLastNode(true);
            this.navigationNodeCollection.add(nnci);
        }

        clientContext.load(this.navigationNodeCollection);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function runCode() {
    addNavigationNodes();
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert("Nodes are added to the navigation.");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           var navArray = [
{ title: "Microsoft", url: "http://www.microsoft.com", isExternal: true },
{ title: "Google", url: "http://www.google.com", isExternal: true },
{ title: "Bing", url: "http://www.bing.com", isExternal: true }
           ];

           function checkArray() {
               for (var i = 0; i < navArray.length; i++) {
                   var navObject = navArray[i];

                   alert(navObject.title);
               }
           }

           var navigationNodeCollection = null;
           var nnci = null;
           var item = null;
           var quickLaunchNodes = null;
           function addNavigationNodes() {
               debugger;
               var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

               if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
                   //var web = clientContext.get_web();

                   // Get the Quick Launch navigation node collection.
                   // this.quickLaunchNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_quickLaunch();

                   // Get the Top Navigation navigation node collection.
                   this.navigationNodeCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_navigation().get_quickLaunch();
                 //  this.quickLaunchNodes = navigationNodeCollection.get_children();
                   //this.navigationNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_topNavigationBar();

                 //  for (var i = 0; i < navArray.length; i++) {
                     //  var navObject = navArray[i];
                   var navTitle = "QMS360";//navObject.title;
                   var navUrl = "http://www.bing.com";//navObject.url;
                   var navIsExternal = true;//navObject.isExternal;

                       // Set properties for a new navigation node.
                       this.nnci = new SP.NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
                       nnci.set_title(navTitle);
                       nnci.set_url(navUrl);
                       nnci.set_isExternal(navIsExternal);

                       // Create node as the last node in the collection.
                       nnci.set_asLastNode(true);
                       this.navigationNodeCollection.add(nnci);


                   //}
                       clientContext.load(this.navigationNodeCollection);
                   //clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
                       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.getChildNavNodes), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
               }
           }

           function runCode() {
               debugger;
               addNavigationNodes();
           }

           function onQuerySucceeded() {
               alert("Nodes are added to the navigation.");
           }

           function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
               alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
           }


            function getChildNavNodes() {
                debugger;


                var item = null;
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                this.collChildNavNode = navigationNodeCollection.get_item(3).get_children();

                //alert("complete");

                var navArray = [
{ title: "Microsoft", url: "http://www.microsoft.com", isExternal: true },
{ title: "Google", url: "http://www.google.com", isExternal: true },
{ title: "Bing", url: "http://www.bing.com", isExternal: true }
                ];


                for (var i = 0; i < navArray.length; i++) {
                    var navObject = navArray[i];
                    var navTitle = navObject.title;
                    var navUrl = navObject.url;
                    var navIsExternal = navObject.isExternal;

                    this.nnci = new SP.NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
                    nnci.set_title(navTitle);
                    nnci.set_url(navUrl);
                    nnci.set_isExternal(navIsExternal);

                    // Create node as the last node in the collection.
                    nnci.set_asLastNode(true);
                    this.collChildNavNode.add(nnci);
                }
                clientContext.load(collChildNavNode);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.createNavNode), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
            }

            function onQuerySucceeded() {

                alert("Created navigation node.");
            }

            function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
```